# Can someone prove (or reference) this summation equation from wikipedia?

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, summation

Wikipedia has a [number of equations for approximating a summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Growth_rates).  Unfortunately, there are no proofs or references.

For example:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i)^c i^d b^i = \theta(n^d \log(n)^c b^n)
$$
for non-negative real $b\gt1$, $c$, $d$.

Does anyone know how to prove this, or where I can find a reference that proves it?

Comment: What you have written is not true for $b=1$ since $$
\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i)^c i^d = \theta(n^{d+1} \log(n)^c)
$$

Comment: Also obviously not true for $|b| < 1$.

Comment: You're right.  I forgot the qualifications in the article.  I've updated it to reflect that.

Comment: $\Theta$ rather than $\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously 
\[ \log(n)^cn^d b^n \le \sum_{i=1}^n \log(i)^c i^d b^i \]
On the other hand
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n b^i &\le \frac{b^{n+1} - 1}{b-1}\\
      &= b^n \cdot \frac{b - \frac 1{b^{n-1}}}{b-1}\\
      &\le b^n \cdot \frac b{b-1}\\
\end{align*}
So 
\[\sum_{i=1}^n \log(i)^c i^d b^i\le \log(n)^c n^d\sum_{i=1}^n  b^i \le \log(n)^c n^d b^n \cdot \frac b{b-1}. \]

Comment: This proves an upper bound, but not the lower bound, right?

Comment: The lower bound is in the first line, note that obviously a sum is bounded below by one of its summands.

Comment: Got my less than and greater than backwards :)

Answer (score 1):

It is true if $b > 1$.  Let $a_i(n) = \dfrac{\log(n-i)^c (n-i)^d b^{n-i}}{\log(n)^c n^d b^n} = \left(\dfrac{\log(n-i)}{\log(n)}\right)^c \left(1-\dfrac{i}{n}\right)^d b^{-i}$.  Then the claim is
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i(n) = \Theta(1) \ \text{as}\ n \to \infty$$ 
We have $a_0(n) = 1$, while $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_i(n) = b^{-i}$ for each $i$, with
$0 \le a_i(n) \le  b^{-i}$.  By the Dominated Convergence Theorem and the fact that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty b^{-i}$ converges, 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i(n) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} a_i(n) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty b^{-i} = \frac{1}{1-1/b} = \frac{b}{b-1} $$